# .ipa can not update app on iTunes, app just appears grey

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, app-store-connect, itunes

I currently have an app on the app store and am trying to test to see if the update work. I've created an ad hoc archive and exported it to a .ipa.

So I currently have the app on my phone, when I use go to iTunes and click update app, the app copies to the phone and then goes grey. It does change from here.

If I uninstall the current version of the app from my phone and then use iTune to install the app, it works perfectly.

Anyone know whats wrong?

Comment: That should work _if the appstore and adhoc builds were built using the same developer account_. Were they?

Comment: the app was originally built by another company

Answer (score 0):

You need to build the updated app using the same developer account as the appstore one. If you can't do that, you're out of luck - you *should* be able to replace the app, but the keychain won't work...

Comment: Not without having access to the appstore developer account. You need production certificate private keys and an admin login to iTunesConnect.